# How to directly use class name as a static attribute in PHP

Tags: php, class, static

I have a class name and I want to use the name to get static attributes from the class. Of course I don't want to have to write the class name again and again. All I could come with is this.

```
class MyClass
{
    public static $shopClass = 'super\Long\Class\name\I\want\to\have\only\Here';

    public function do($classesStaticAttribute){

        $shopClass = self::$shopClass; //I would like to avoid this row...
        $this->doSomeStuff($shopClass::$$classesStaticAttribute);

    }
}
```

Is there any way I could avoid the `$shopClass = self::$shopClass` row and access the attribute directly? `{self::$shopClass}::$$classesStaticAttribute` does not work.

Comment: so here you want to access a class attributes by using class name as static attribute right??

Comment: yep, id do.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply import the class symbol via `use`, ie

```
use super\Long\Class\name\I\want\to\have\only\Here as Shop;

class MyClass
{
    public function do($classesStaticAttribute){

        $this->doSomeStuff(Shop::$$classesStaticAttribute);

    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, say you want the `$shopClass` property to be settable externally, you can simply use

```
$this->doSomeStuff(constant(self::$shopClass . '::$' . $classesStaticAttribute));
```

See http://php.net/manual/function.constant.php

Comment: Cool, I forget I could do that :) It only wouldn't "work" if I needed something like `MyClass::$shopClass::$attribute` in a different file (i would have to use the `use` in that file too instead...), but fortunately I don't need to now :)

Comment: @Charlestone I've added another method